# How do I combine docker-compose scaling and load balanced port exposure?

Tags: docker

If you tell docker-compose to scale a service, and do NOT expose its ports,

```
docker-compose scale dataservice=2
```

There will be two IPs in the network that the dns name `dataservice` will resolve to.  So, services that reach it by hostname will load balance.

I would also like to do this to the edge proxy as well.   The point would be that

```
docker-compose scale edgeproxy=2
```

Would cause `edgeproxy` to resolve to one of 2 possible IP Addresses.

But the semantics of exposing ports is wrong for this.  If I expose:

```
  8443:8443
```

Then it will try to bind each `edgeproxy` to be bound to host 8443.  What I want is more like:

```
0.0.0.0:8443:edgeproxy:8443
```

Where when you try to come into the docker network via host 8443, it randomly selects an edgeproxy:8443 IP to bind the incoming TCP connection to.

Is there an alternative to just do a port-forward?  I want a port that can get me in to talk to any ip that will resolve as `edgeproxy`.

Answer (score 0):

This is provided by swarm mode. You can enable a single node swarm cluster with:

```
docker swarm init
```

And then deploy your compose file as a stack with:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml $stack_name
```

There are quite a few differences from docker compose including:

1. Swarm doesn't build images
2. You manage the target state with `docker service` commands, trying to stop a container with `docker stop` won't work since swarm will restart it
3. The compose file needs to be in a v3 syntax
4. Networks will be an overlay network, and not attachable by containers outside of swarm, by default

One of the main changes is that exposed ports are published on an ingress network managed by swarm mode, and connections are round robin load balanced to your containers. You can also define a replica count inside the compose file, eliminating the need to run a scale command.

See more at: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/